# 530 Permission denied in FTP connection

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

I am trying to connect to vsftpd server on CentOS which is running on a VM over my Windows system. I'm trying to connect through a java API based FTP client on windows system. But I get this error:

> Error 530: Permission denied.

Here's the code:

```
client.setRemoteHost(ipAddress);

client.setRemotePort(port);

client.connect();

client.login("root", "password");
```

I get the error on the client.login("root", "password") statement of my java code. The first three lines of the code execute fine. The password is the same as my root password. What else should I check for to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does root/password work using a standard ftp program?

Comment: Nope! I tried through filezilla. Does't work.

Comment: Then root/password is not allowed to connect through FTP (which is not an unreasonable security precaution), so you'd have to try with another account.

Comment: Do you know how to set or find the password that vsftpd would accept? Doesn't look like its looking for the root password.

Comment: Have you got another account on CentOS?  Then try that with filezilla.

Comment: And if you don't have a non-root account, someone needs to give you the lesson / lecture about how it is dangerous to do everything logged in as `root`.

Comment: I do have a non root account. But vsftpd won't start on that account. I think it works only on root.